# Implicit function theorem and fiber

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, implicit-function-theorem

Let $\pi:X\to T$ be a proper surjective holomorphic mapping of maximal rank from a complex manifold $X$ to a complex manifold $T$. Let $X_t=\pi^{-1}(t)$. Then $X_t$ is the fibre over $t$, or the compact complex submanifold of $X$ corresponding to the parameter $t\in T$.

[image]

I can't see clearly why $\psi_p|_{U_p\cap X_t}\cong U'_p\cap C^n\times\{t\}$ by implicit function. I think by implicit function theorem we can only get the case for $t=0$. However I can't see we can find a general $U_p$ s.t. the $t$ around $0$ can share with $0$ by using the common $U_p$.

Comment: It's really an application of the inverse function theorem to see that a submersion looks locally (in appropriate coordinates) like a projection $\pi(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1,\dots,x_m)$ [see, e.g., Guillemin and Pollack, p. 20]. However, the depth of this result (usually called Ehresmann's Theorem) is to make it global along the fibers.  I presume that follows in the portion you haven't included.

Comment: What book is this screenshot from?